# Return array from table

Tags: php, arrays, extract

I have field in my table with data:   DE;RO;US;
Question is how extract data in array as:

```
$array = array('DE', 'RO', 'US');
```

Comment: What table? What fields? Can you provide and example of your input data?

Comment: I have table 'ad' and field in is 'pays_autorise'

Answer (score 2):

use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.
Like this :

```
$string = 'DE;RO;US;';

$arr = explode(';',$string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `explode()` here.

`$array = explode(';', $data);`

The variable data is the result of you database query.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

BTW: Your way to save things in the database is not good. Have a look at database normalization.